# Error AES - Standard SymmetricAlgorithm, “Padding is invalid and cannot be removed”

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, aes

I am using `AES - Standard SymmetricAlgorithm,` for Encrypting and Decrypting string. String is encrypting successfully but when it comes to decrypt the compiler gives me the exception i.e

> ***“Padding is invalid and cannot be removed”.***

I have created a demo console application for testing, please have a look on below code.

The Main Method:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var content = "5466160057107706";
    var key = "E546C8DF278CD5931069B522E695D4F2";

    var encrypted = EncryptString(content, key);
    Console.WriteLine(encrypted);
    var decrypted = DecryptString(encrypted, key);
    Console.WriteLine(decrypted);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Method added for Encryption:

```
public static string EncryptString(string text, string keyString)
{
    var key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(keyString);
    using (var aesAlg = Aes.Create())
    {
        using (var encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(key, aesAlg.IV))
        {
            using (var msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (var csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                using (var swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
                {
                    swEncrypt.Write(text);
                }
                var iv = aesAlg.IV;
                var decryptedContent = msEncrypt.ToArray();
                var result = new byte[iv.Length + decryptedContent.Length];
                Buffer.BlockCopy(iv, 0, result, 0, iv.Length);
                Buffer.BlockCopy(decryptedContent, 0, result, iv.Length, decryptedContent.Length);
                return Convert.ToBase64String(result);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Method added for Decryption:

```
public static string DecryptString(string cipherText, string keyString)
{
    var fullCipher = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);
    var iv = new byte[16];
    var cipher = new byte[16];
    Buffer.BlockCopy(fullCipher, 0, iv, 0, iv.Length);
    Buffer.BlockCopy(fullCipher, iv.Length, cipher, 0, iv.Length);
    var key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(keyString);
    using (var aesAlg = Aes.Create())
    {
        using (var decryptor = aesAlg.CreateDecryptor(key, iv))
        {
            string result;
            using (var msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(cipher))
            {
                using (var csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                {
                    using (var srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))
                    {
                        result = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the Error Snap which occurs in the `DecryptString()` method:

[image]

Any advice, how to solve this issue?

Comment: Variable names can be helpful or not: `decryptedContent = msEncrypt`, not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clue:
`var cipher = new byte[16];`

Why are you assuming your cipher would be ONLY 16 bytes ? What if it is more than this ?

In fact, if I run this program and debug, I see that your cipher is 32 bytes.

So, the following 2 line changes makes it work:

```
var cipher = new byte[32];

Buffer.BlockCopy(fullCipher, iv.Length, cipher, 0, cipher.Length);
```

In any case, you would need to dynamically determine your size of cipher.

Comment: To clarify for others, the encrypt code above uses the default aesAlg.IV value which is a random array of 16 bytes.  Thus, you change the decrypt to:

`var iv = new byte[16];
var cipher = new byte[fullCipher.Length - 16];

Buffer.BlockCopy(fullCipher, 0, iv, 0, iv.Length);
Buffer.BlockCopy(fullCipher, iv.Length, cipher, 0, cipher.Length);`